# Is there a way I can mask a URL parameter in Node.JS? (Converting a question mark to a slash)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a Node.JS polling app.

Currently the link for a poll is:
https://beta.manuthecoder.repl.co/v/?id=1

I would like to mask the query parameter, and the new URL to be: https://beta.manuthecoder.repl.co/v/1

`/1` would be the query parameter for ID
Here's my code:

```js
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
const httpserver = http.Server(app);
const io = socketio(httpserver);
const gamedirectory = path.join(__dirname, "public");
app.use(express.static(gamedirectory));
console.log(gamedirectory)

httpserver.listen(3000);
```

The code for the http part is here:

```js
const gamedirectory = path.join(__dirname, "public");
app.use(express.static(gamedirectory));
```

Comment: Try nginx. Nginx helps to modify your URL, check nginx doc.
It is also possible in node js write a API in node and read all query params in that API and modify or create new URL manually

Comment: You can write a middleware that modifies the request: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Comment: How do I use NGIX in repl?

Comment: @jabaa - Thanks for the suggestion! Could I see an example? Thanks!

Comment: I also know how to do this via htaccess but i don't know how to implement it in repl.it

Comment: There are multiple examples in the link in my previous comment. You can access query parameters with `req.query` and you can access the path with `req.path`.